# Call to a member function fetch_array() in this code

Tags: php

```
public function Login ($admin_user,$admin_pass)
    {
    try
        {
            $select = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wild WHERE admin_user=".$admin_user." AND admin_pass=".$admin_pass."");
            $row = $select->fetch_array(); //i get error here
            $no_rows = $row->num_rows;

            if ($no_rows == 1) 
            {
                $_SESSION['admin_id'] = true;
                $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['admin_id'];
                $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $row['admin_user'];
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }                           
        }           
    }
```

I have problem to fetch data so help me.

Comment: try to use like "SELECT * FROM wild WHERE admin_user='".$admin_user."' AND admin_pass='".$admin_pass."'"

Answer (score 0):

You have not tagged any other framework. So I am answering assuming its core PHP. I also assume that you are using one DB class for you DB queries purpose.

First please check you have included the DB class,  and there is `fetch_array` method available.

Secondly, never ever put PHP variables directly into the SQL string.

```
    $select = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wild WHERE admin_user=".$admin_user." AND admin_pass=".$admin_pass."");
```

This will enhance chances of SQL injections. In your DB class I assume there must be method to bind variables into SQL string. If yes then use it.

Also put more detailed question - so that we can get more ideas. Please let me know if you still get error.